# Xojo HTMLviewer showing blank page for OAuth2.0 login

Tags: xojo

I'm trying to set up an OAuth2.0 flow for ORCID with Xojo. I found a sample project on github for Facebook and modified the code for the URL and ClientKey I set up with ORCID. When I use the same URL in Firefox it works perfectly, however when I try to load the page in the HTMLviewer it just shows a blank page. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that HTMLViewer in Xojo is not the same as a full web browser. Some oAuth flows are requiring higher security standards than Xojo can provide.

Google is even going so far as to [prevent low-security embedded browsers from performing the oAuth flow](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/upcoming-security-changes-to-googles-oauth-2.0-authorization-endpoint.html). They now recommend you make the request with the user's default system browser.

It seems like you will need to change your design to use the system browser instead of the embedded one.